# How to update the all the table values using a singe query

Tags: sql-server-2005

hai friends

i am having the table like this

```
TBLKEY      EMPKEY                         EMPNAME
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
1           101                            RAJA
2           105                            RAJA
3           106                            RAJA
4           110                            RAJA
```

i want to to update like this

```
TBLKEY      EMPKEY                         EMPNAME
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
1           101                            RAJA
2           105                            POOJA
3           106                            THRIU
4           110                            POOJA
```

here i sholud use only one query.i run that query i sholud get the output like this not updating one by one

Comment: There is a tick  symbol at the left hand side of the answers if the answer give you solution please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=96260

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/13/10126702/update-single-column-with-multiple-rows.aspx

Sure this links will give you idea to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET EMPNAME = CASE WHEN TBLKEY = 2 THEN 'POOJA'
                   WHEN TBLKEY = 3 THEN 'THRIU'
                   WHEN TBLKEY = 4 THEN 'POOJA' END
WHERE TBLKEY IN ( 2, 3, 4 )
```